# OpenVPN: Can see devices, connected to my local network

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have OpenVPN server installed on debian (public ip 90.191.183.193). I run OpenVPN client on Windows 10, put generated .ovpn file and connect. I can see devices connected to the network the server is running on, however, I can also see devices, connected to my local network, which I don't like. Here are some files:

**openvpn.conf**

```
server 192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0
verb 3
key /etc/openvpn/pki/private/90.191.183.193.key
ca /etc/openvpn/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/pki/issued/90.191.183.193.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/pki/dh.pem
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/pki/ta.key
key-direction 0
keepalive 10 60
persist-key
persist-tun

proto tcp
# Rely on Docker to do port mapping, internally always 1194
port 1194
dev tun0
status /tmp/openvpn-status.log

user nobody
group nogroup
comp-lzo no

### Route Configurations Below
route 192.168.254.0 255.255.255.0

### Push Configurations Below
push "block-outside-dns"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
push "comp-lzo no"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

**ovpn_env.sh**

```
declare -x OVPN_AUTH=
declare -x OVPN_CIPHER=
declare -x OVPN_CLIENT_TO_CLIENT=
declare -x OVPN_CN=90.191.183.193
declare -x OVPN_COMP_LZO=0
declare -x OVPN_DEFROUTE=1
declare -x OVPN_DEVICE=tun
declare -x OVPN_DEVICEN=0
declare -x OVPN_DISABLE_PUSH_BLOCK_DNS=0
declare -x OVPN_DNS=1
declare -x OVPN_DNS_SERVERS=([0]="8.8.8.8" [1]="8.8.4.4")
declare -x OVPN_ENV=/etc/openvpn/ovpn_env.sh
declare -x OVPN_EXTRA_CLIENT_CONFIG=()
declare -x OVPN_EXTRA_SERVER_CONFIG=()
declare -x OVPN_FRAGMENT=
declare -x OVPN_KEEPALIVE='10 60'
declare -x OVPN_MTU=
declare -x OVPN_NAT=0
declare -x OVPN_PORT=1194
declare -x OVPN_PROTO=tcp
declare -x OVPN_PUSH=()
declare -x OVPN_ROUTES=([0]="192.168.254.0/24")
declare -x OVPN_SERVER=192.168.255.0/24
declare -x OVPN_SERVER_URL=tcp://90.191.183.193
declare -x OVPN_TLS_CIPHER=
```

At the end of *user*.ovpn file is `redirect-gateway def1`

I use **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  ovpn:
    image: kylemanna/openvpn:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./ovpn-data:/etc/openvpn:rw
    ports:
      - 1194:1194/tcp
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
```

And two bash scripts to initialize and create clients:

**init.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -x
docker compose run --rm ovpn ovpn_genconfig -u tcp://90.191.183.193
docker compose run --rm ovpn ovpn_initpki
```

**create_client.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
docker compose run --rm ovpn easyrsa build-client-full $1 nopass
docker compose run --rm ovpn ovpn_getclient $1 > $1.ovpn
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Connecting to the VPN doesn't disconnect you from your local network. This is expected. This is like you put additional network card into your computer. Generally I don't see a point why disabling an access to the LAN is useful.

Comment: I have devices with repeating ip addresses, which create conflicts.

Comment: Do you have the same network block here and there? Then you have to renumber one of them. And this is the lesson: never use "default" neworks like 192.168.0.0 or 192.168.1.0 or 192.168.88.0 in the office, spend 30 minutes or so on network planning.

Comment: What do you mean "network planning"? I have to connect to my vpn server from ANY network. And if the network I am connecting from has same ip addresses, I want to fully connect to vpn, not seeing devices from the network I am connecting from. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I've just seen "block-local" flag. Where do I need to put it and how to use it?

Comment: So is it possible to block local network access? Like to "remove another network card" and how?

Comment: No, it's not possible. It is "second card", yet it's virtual. The physical connection is *required*. // Yes, you can connect to any network, but if network blocks overlap, you'll get problems. Usually just something will not be accessible, but in extreme cases there can be bigger problems (no network access while you are attempting to be in the VPN). Renumbering (changing network block on one side) is the *only* solution to these. // I don't know which flag you're talking about; there is `man openvpn` installed with openvpn package, which is the definitive documentation for the software.

Comment: Also, I see absolutely no point in running OpenVPN inside Docker. Docker alone has quite complicated networking, and VPN is not an easy networking subject, it must be a nightmare to grasp them together.